# in perforce, can a file have multiple actions?

Tags: perforce

According to the [docs for `fstat`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/fstat.html), an action for a file can be one of: add, edit, delete, branch, move/add, move/delete, integrate, import, purge, or archive.

Is it ever possible for a file in my workspace to have multiple actions at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you sometimes can perform multiple actions on a file (e.g. do `p4 integrate`/`p4 move`/`p4 copy` on a file followed by a `p4 edit` on it), `p4 fstat` will list only one `action` field.